# Casting Strings into Birthdates (that aren't in the future)

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am casting mm/dd/yy strings into dates in redshift using CAST AS DATE `CAST(birth_str AS DATE) AS birth_date`. The conversion handles the components correctly but the year is being converted into future times whenever it falls below 1970. For example:

```
birth_str   birth_date
07/19/84    1984-07-19
02/07/66    2066-02-07
06/24/84    1984-06-24
01/31/64    2064-01-31
12/08/62    2062-12-08
02/21/36    2036-02-21
02/19/37    2037-02-19
07/01/74    1974-07-01
08/25/50    2050-08-25
08/31/39    2039-08-31
```

Is there a best practice for getting dates to not fall into the future?

Is there not an argument for this in the cast? (I looked everywhere but I am finding nothing.) Otherwise, I am envisioning the best path forward is testing for the cast date being in the future and then just doing string surgery on the miscreants before recasting them into reasonable dates.

Basically:

- if not future date: great.
- if future date:

  - peel out all the date components
  - slap a 19 onto the yy
  - glue everything back together
  - cast into date.

Is this as good as it gets? (I was a bit surprised I could find no one has come up with a better way around this issue already.)

Comment: Can you have the input files generated with a 4 digit year? That way you don't have this issue

Comment: Good point. We will be adding this to future data specifications. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a best practice?  Absolutely!  Don't store dates as strings.  Store dates as `date`.  That is why SQL has native types.

In your case, you could use conditional logic:

```
select (case when cast(birth_str AS DATE) < current_date
             then cast(birth_str AS DATE)
             else cast(birth_str AS DATE) - interval '100 year'
        end) as birth_date
```

Or since Redshift [can't handle intervals](https://github.com/OHDSI/SqlRender/issues/62) you can go with this:

```
SELECT (CASE
            WHEN birth_str::DATE < CURRENT_DATE
            THEN birth_str::DATE
            ELSE ADD_MONTHS(birth_str::DATE, -1200)
        END) AS birth_date
```

Comment: Yup. Unfortunately the reason we are casting things at all is because they were shipped and loaded up from text files. Is there a way to maintain types during transfer?

Comment: @leerssej . . . If the source files have only two digit years, then you can convert them to dates, but you run the risk of future dates.  Under the circumstances, you might be better fixing the dates after importing them.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a CASE to check the converted DATE IS greater than TODAY or not. If Yes, Just minus 100 years from the results as below.

One Question: Is there any chance of having dates like 02/21/14 which can be belongs to 1900 or 2000?

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN CAST('02/21/36' AS DATE) >GETDATE() THEN DATEADD(YY,-100,CAST('02/21/36' AS DATE)) 
    ELSE CAST('02/21/36' AS DATE) 
END
```

Comment: Sadly, yes there is an inherent ambiguity of whether the birthdate can be for a 5 year old or a 105 year old. Far more likely that it is for a 5yo though.

Comment: That's the tricky part :( That case you need help of other column to determine the year belong to 1900 or 2000? I check the conversion for 02/21/19 and its returning 2019-02-21 and not possible to define its correct or it should be from 1900. Do you have any indication in any other field?